# Unity runs code only at some points while at some other points it refuses to run it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity, and I'm following a tutorial on how to make a chess game. Although in the chessboard script everything compiles, and the application runs smoothly it just doesn't do one thing, or it does it only sometimes. Basically as I hover over tiles with my mouse it should highlight them by changing the Layer, but it doesn't do so.

Below I'm posting the update method of the chessboard.cs script and a screenshot of the User Interface as I run my game. Thank you in advance!

**Chessboard.cs**

```
void Update()
{
   

    if (!currentCamera)
    {
        currentCamera = Camera.main;
        return;
    }

    
    RaycastHit info;
    Ray ray = currentCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out info, 100, LayerMask.GetMask("tile")))
    {
       
        Vector2Int hitPosition = LookUpTileIndex(info.transform.gameObject);

        if(currentHover == -Vector2Int.one)
        {
            currentHover = hitPosition;
            tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
           

        }

        if(currentHover != hitPosition) 
        {
            tiles[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("tile");
            currentHover = hitPosition;
            tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
            Debug.Log(tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer);

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (chessPieces[hitPosition.x,hitPosition.y]!=null) {
                
                //is it our turn?
                if(true)
                {
                    currentlyDragging = chessPieces[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y];
                }

            }

        }

        if (currentlyDragging != null && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Vector2Int previousPosition = new Vector2Int(currentlyDragging.currentX,currentlyDragging.currentY);

            bool validMove = MoveTo(currentlyDragging, hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y);

            if(!validMove) {
                
                currentlyDragging.transform.position = getTileCenter(previousPosition.x,previousPosition.y);
                currentlyDragging = null;

            }

        }

        else
        {
            if (currentHover != -Vector2Int.one)
            {
                tiles[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("tile");
                currentHover = -Vector2Int.one;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

**EDIT**

```
 using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chessboard : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Art Stuff")]
    [SerializeField] private Material tileMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private float tileSize = 1.15f;
    [SerializeField] private float yOffset = 0.15f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 boardCenter = Vector3.zero;

    [Header("Prefabs && Materials")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] prefabs;
    [SerializeField] private Material[] teamMaterials;

    private ChessPieces[,] chessPieces;
    private ChessPieces currentlyDragging;

    private const int TILE_COUNT_X = 8;
    private const int TILE_COUNT_Y = 8;
    

    private GameObject[,] tiles;
    private Camera currentCamera;
    

    private Vector2Int currentHover;

    private Vector3 bounds;



    void Awake()
    {
        
       

        GenerateAllTiles(tileSize, TILE_COUNT_X, TILE_COUNT_Y);

        spawnAllPieces();

        positionAllPieces();
    }

    void Update()
    {
       

        if (!currentCamera)
        {
            currentCamera = Camera.main;
            return;
        }

        
        RaycastHit info;
        Ray ray = currentCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out info, 100, LayerMask.GetMask("tile")))
        {
           
            Vector2Int hitPosition = LookUpTileIndex(info.transform.gameObject);

            if(currentHover == -Vector2Int.one)
            {
                currentHover = hitPosition;
                tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
               

            }

            if(currentHover != hitPosition) 
            {
                tiles[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("tile");
                currentHover = hitPosition;
                tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
                Debug.Log(tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer);

            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                if (chessPieces[hitPosition.x,hitPosition.y]!=null) {
                    
                    //is it our turn?
                    if(true)
                    {
                        currentlyDragging = chessPieces[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y];
                    }

                }

            }

            if (currentlyDragging != null && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                Vector2Int previousPosition = new Vector2Int(currentlyDragging.currentX,currentlyDragging.currentY);

                bool validMove = MoveTo(currentlyDragging, hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y);

                if(!validMove) {
                    
                    currentlyDragging.transform.position = getTileCenter(previousPosition.x,previousPosition.y);
                    currentlyDragging = null;

                }

            }

            else
            {
                if (currentHover != -Vector2Int.one)
                {
                    tiles[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("tile");
                    currentHover = -Vector2Int.one;
                }
            }
        }
    }

  

    private void GenerateAllTiles(float tileSize,int tileCountX, int tileCountY){

        yOffset += transform.position.y;
        bounds = new Vector3((tileCountX / 2) * tileSize, 0, (tileCountY / 2) * tileSize)+ boardCenter;

        tiles = new GameObject[TILE_COUNT_X, TILE_COUNT_Y];
        for(int x = 0; x < tileCountX; x++) { 
            for(int y = 0; y < tileCountY; y++)
            {
                tiles[x,y] = generateSingleTile(tileSize, x, y);
            }
        }

    }

    private GameObject generateSingleTile(float tileSize, int x, int y)
    {
        GameObject tileObject = new GameObject(string.Format("X:{0},Y:{1}", x, y));

        tileObject.transform.parent = transform;

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        tileObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        tileObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileMaterial;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4];

        vertices[0] = new Vector3(x * tileSize, yOffset, y * tileSize)-bounds;
        vertices[1] = new Vector3(x * tileSize, yOffset, (y + 1) * tileSize)-bounds;
        vertices[2] = new Vector3((x+1) * tileSize, yOffset, y  * tileSize)-bounds;
        vertices[3] = new Vector3((x+1) * tileSize, yOffset, (y + 1) * tileSize)-bounds;

        int[] tris = { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = tris;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

        tileObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

        tileObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("tile");

        return tileObject;
    }

    private void spawnAllPieces()
    {

        chessPieces = new ChessPieces[TILE_COUNT_X, TILE_COUNT_Y];

        int whiteTeam = 0, blackTeam = 1;

        chessPieces[0, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Rook, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[1, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Knight, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[2, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Bishop,whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[3, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Queen, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[4, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.King, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[5, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Bishop,whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[6, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Knight, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[7, 0] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Rook, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[0, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[1, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[2, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[3, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[4, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[5, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[6, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);
        chessPieces[7, 1] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, whiteTeam);

        chessPieces[7, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Rook, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[6, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Knight, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[5, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Bishop, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[4, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Queen, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[3, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.King, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[2, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Bishop, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[1, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Knight, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[0, 7] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Rook, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[0, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[1, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[2, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[3, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[4, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[5, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[6, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);
        chessPieces[7, 6] = spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType.Pawn, blackTeam);

    }

    private ChessPieces spawnSinglePiece(ChessPieceType type,int team)
    {

        ChessPieces cp = Instantiate(prefabs[(int)type -1],transform).GetComponent<ChessPieces>();

        cp.type = type;
        cp.team = team;

        cp.transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)0.1,(float)0.1,(float)0.1);

        cp.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = teamMaterials[team];

        
        
        
        return cp;

       
    }
    

    private void positionAllPieces()
    {
        for(int x = 0;x<TILE_COUNT_X;x++) 
            for(int y = 0;y<TILE_COUNT_Y;y++)
                if (chessPieces[x,y] != null)
                    positionSinglePiece(x,y,true);

    }

    private void positionSinglePiece(int x , int y, bool force = false)
    {
        chessPieces[x, y].currentX = x;
        chessPieces[x,y].currentY = y;
        chessPieces[x, y].transform.position = getTileCenter(x,y);
    }

    private Vector3 getTileCenter(int x,int y)
    {
        return new Vector3(x*tileSize,yOffset,y*tileSize)-bounds + new Vector3(tileSize/2,0,tileSize/2);
    }

    private Vector2Int LookUpTileIndex(GameObject hitInfo)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < TILE_COUNT_X; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < TILE_COUNT_Y; y++)
                if (tiles[x, y] == hitInfo)
                    return new Vector2Int(x, y);







        return -Vector2Int.one;
    } 
    
    private bool MoveTo(ChessPieces cp, int x, int y)
    {
        Vector2Int previousPosition = new Vector2Int(cp.currentX, cp.currentY);

        chessPieces[x, y] = cp;
        chessPieces[previousPosition.x, previousPosition.y] = null;

        positionSinglePiece(x, y);

        return true;    
    }
```

}

Here is the entire code @TheNomad, I think that what you are referring to in your comment might be the code into the function spawnSinglePiece()

Comment: Are your tiles on the expected layer `tile` ? Is a distance of 100 enough? .. hard to tell for us from here .. debug your code and check why it doesn't enter the code block you expect it to ...

Comment: Your camera is slightly angled and the tile colliders protrude. Is it possible that the tile in front catches the raycast?

Comment: Why did you add a return in `if (!currentCamera)`? If you set it, what's the problem? Why skip a frame? Also, where is the hovering layer code? You set it to layer `Hover`, but where is it used? The problem might also be where you use this, not necessarily where you determine to use it, such as your `Update()`.

Comment: @derHugo Yes! its enough a distance of a hundred, because sometimes it works just fine, just some other times it doesnt, I'm wondering if it could be an issue related to my own computer, Also when it does enter the code block( the few times it does work) it also executes the debug.log and shows the layer its actually hitting the tile!

Comment: @TheNomad about why it is returning !currentCamera I have no idea, I followed a tutorial and he was doing so, me myself I'm not sure what that line of code does. Ill soon send the missing code

Comment: @Lolloroma114 Don't take this a wrong way, but if you want to use Unity, you need to learn C# first. You can't skip this step. You don't learn Unity by writing code blindly without knowing what it does. You can't drive a car just by learning to drive if you skip lessons about the traffic rules. You'll end up watching random multipart tutorials and skip dependencies and wonder why you have errors. Stack Overflow is full of such Unity questions cos people prefer shortcuts. There are no shortcuts. Learn C# first, even beginner level, then try Unity. Trust me. It will save you a ton of headaches.

Comment: I do know a bit of C#, and plus I'm using this a stepping stone for learning more! @TheNomad, by the way I posted full code, and trust me I know somme bit of programming and sometimes I do solve issues even in new frameworks such as unity, just this time I've been searching deeply but haven't found none who has similar issues, and also such a strange one, that it works at times and doesnt at others, that's why I asked here

Comment: @Voidsay, could be the case, but  it still don't explain the times the code works!

Comment: There is always the floating point rounding. If you're working on a really small scale I could see the raycast hitting one or the other depending on how the dice roll.

Comment: @Lolloroma114 Sorry, but if you don't know `if return`, then the "bit of C#" you know is not enough. Your answer seems to show you took it personal. Why? Just trust when someone that knows more than you and gives you advice and instead of saying "I know what I am doing" say "OK, I'll check it out" if you want to learn something properly not just "a bit".  But moving on, tell me the results when you debugged it. What are the code steps it took? (No, I don't mean Debug.Log, I mean real debugging). That is your easiest method of finding the problem. If you need help on how to use it, let me know.

Comment: @Voidsay if it hit the other depending on how the dice would roll at least the other would highlight, but it doesn't do so the times it doesnt work. Just nothing highlights those times no matter what I hover onto, instead when it works it actually highlights every single tile as I hover over.

Comment: @TheNomad Well I really haven't taken it personally, I sincerly appreciate any feed-back or suggestion as I'm very determined to learn, so definitely if you have some advice you think I should follow given your experience I'd be very happy to listen to it. My previous reply wasn't out of anger or anything, I'm thankful for every answer I get here cause on the first place nobody has to solve my problem, so if anybody does it even if they don't need to it is very much appreciated, really if you have suggestions on some steps I ahould take to learn I'd be happy to listen to it!

Comment: @TheNomad, I'll try the real debug!

Comment: Before you start, I have one question regarding derHugo's comment about the distance. You said that *"Basically as I hover over tiles with my mouse it should highlight them by changing the Layer, but it doesn't do so."* Every other sentence in our post and comments suggests that *sometimes* they get highlighted but other times not. My question is: is the same tile sometimes highlighted, sometimes not? Or are we talking about different ones? Also, second question is, is the tile that gets highlighted once, get highlighted a second time or must you stop and start Play Mode again to make it work?

Comment: @TheNomad, sorry for the late reply, I think we have different UTC times, by the way yes, the same tile, or actually all of the tiles, get highlighted on hover when the application works ( few times), and none of the tiles gets highlighted on hover when the application doesnt work, it usually works on the first occurrence of running when I turn on the PC and doesnt do so all of the other times. About the second question the times it works it works smoothly during the whole runtime phase, if I stop and re-run it stops working

Comment: Do you have `ScriptableObjects` in use anywhere?

Comment: @TheNomad Nope, no scriptable objects, just some classes like one for each chessPiece that implement another class that 's called chessPiece (Almost as in interface).

Comment: @TheNomad I forgot to mention, probably because I've just realized, that it used to give an error on line 254 in the spawnSinglePiece method, when I try to set the currentX property (an int that can range from 1 to 8), of the chessPiece[x,y] to the input parameter "x" of the method, it says reference set not to an instance of an object. Now that I added some debug.log it seems its not doing it anymore..... very weird

Comment: Please add the `ChessPieceType` enum to the code in the question. Minor note: this is not "right": `new Vector3((float)0.1,(float)0.1,(float)0.1);` . To convert `double` to `float`, you simply use **f** like so: `new Vector3(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);` . It's just something to remember for the feature. As a small trivia, you do it the same way in Java, C and C++, by the way so this is not just a C# thing.